# Which partition has Windows 10 and grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I cannot seem to repair the Windows 10 partition which hangs at boot so it needs to be reinstalled. In reinstalling and trying to determine which partition has it (the Windows install isn’t all too clear), I booted back to Ubuntu and loaded GParted. It shows that the ext4 is sda5 while NTFS is sda1. Does that equate to the partition numbering of Windows so that partition 1 in Windows is where it should be installed?

Also, I understand that reinstalling Windows 10 will lose GRUB2. If so, how is it reinstalled and does it require another Ubuntu boot disk?

And finally, there is a 469.71MB unallocated space the gparted does not seem to want to allow to be incorporated. Sda5 shows no space left in the resize dialog. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: GParted capture added

Comment: It looks like both Windows and Ubuntu were installed in Legacy mode. In this mode grub is not installed in a partition, but in the drive itself, in this case, `/dev/sda`. Search this site and see questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) for how to reinstall grub after installing Windows.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Comment: The unallocated space is almost too small to bother with, can add it Ubuntu partition if you use an USB stick with the Ubuntu installer on it.  Windows installer should see a NTFS partition, but think you need to choose manual(?) installation instead of automatic(?) so you have some control where Windows goes.

Comment: Yes, I must not only tell Windows which partition but even which version of Windows which is a new one for me. For the unallocated space, it is small but it oddly bothers me to see it there. I guess it harkens back for me to the early PC days when a megabyte was unheard of!

Comment: User68186 I’m not sure how or why the Legacy installation or whether it’s possible to switch from one to the other. Most of my PCs and one laptop are Ubuntu only so I don’t recall the details of how it was installed or whether Ubuntu or Windows came first. I’m curious about that as I don’t typically create dual-boot systems.

Comment: Windows only installs in BIOS boot mode to MBR partitioned drives. And Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. But I thought the system reserved partitions was only on gpt drives? BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: @DonP Please use the "@" before username to notify. Legacy is in the context of the new UEFI versus the old BIOS (Legacy). Old computers used to have BIOS and new ones have UEFI, but allow booting using the Legacy (BIOS), also called compatibility support module (CSM) mode. Here some answers you may find useful: [UEFI and booting from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069536/uefi-and-booting-from-usb/1069792#1069792) and [Installation problems with GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955)

Comment: Yes, sorry I knew that but haven’t posted much for a long time and had forgotten! I knew it was missing something but couldn’t see what it was. No UEFI on this PC as ir likely predates that technology. In any event, my question was simply in trying to figure out whether the partition numbers equated between Windows and Ubuntu and they apparently do so Windows 10 is now reinstalled. I am now struggling to get GRUB working again.

Comment: See the link on my second comment above (third comment from the top). That question deals with getting GRUB working again after installing Windows. You may want to answer your own question by clicking the button below.